# Set and get core data from code in Xcode/cocoa

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm new to Cocoa and xCode, but not programming though.

I have created some some core data and a interface in the interface builder.

Now i need to edit and get some core data from my code. In fact I need to be able to get an "imagepath" to show a picture and to set a new value in the "imagepath".
"imapepath" is a core data attribute.

I have figured out how to insert **a new entry**, but i want **to edit values instead**.

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *places = [NSEntityDescription 
                                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" 
                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [places setValue:[tvarNSOpenPanelObj filename] forKey:@"imagepath"];
```

I hope you guys have some clues ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have loaded your NSManagedObject from CoreData, then you can edit it's values just like any other object. This is stored in your NSManagedObjectContext (ie. just in memory).

You then need to persist this to your backing store at some point, so you need to call save: on your NSManagedObjectContext - and voila, it's saved.

You should read the programming guide for core data:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1

(If you don't know how to load an object from Core Data, read the section on 'Fetching Managed Objects', and then 'Using Managed Objects' to know how to edit them).... in fact, read it all from the beginning to the end. Its invaluable for knowing how to use CoreData correctly and effectively.

Comment: Thanks, a lot of reading to do, but i guess thats the right thing to do ;-)

Comment: OK, I read it, with some difficult in understanding, maybe my english need to be refreshed :-( Anyway, i i'm still not able to get started on it - maybe you could give me a little clue / hint? Compared with Delphi and database / SQL programming, this is quite different :-/

Comment: Ok, the most simple example.... If you want to 'get' an object from core data, you create an NSFetchRequest - you set an entity (Place in your example) on it, and a predicate (a where clause) - and then you call executeFetchRequest: on the managed object context - and it will return the object you are looking for. You can then edit its properties, which changes them on the managed object context (in memory) - you then call save: on the managed object context and it writes it to disk.

Comment: Maybe this is a better resource than reading the documents: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I see what you mean....I have sent some time Reading about the fetching issue. The ting is - i'm using an array controller and bindings via the UI to navigare and ADD/remove data from the core, so my thoughts where to access the data already selected/fetched with the array controller. But maybe I need to see this in another perspective - I need to make a new fetchrequest? Although I already have fetched the data via the array controller ?

Comment: hmnn....Done a lot of reading. Seems like a big project I have involved myself in.
I think i need to manipulate my core data by bindings to my NSArrayController somehow...